# docker: Error response from daemon: dial unix docker.raw.sock: connect: no such file or directory. MacOS

Tags: macos, docker

It happens when I try "docker run -d -p 80:80 docker/getting-started".
I thought it because I don't have enough memory, but after I freed some space problem didn't solve.
I'm running out of ideas

Comment: Is Docker Desktop running?

Comment: @tentative The error seems to be coming from the Daemon, so doesn't that mean the engine is running?

Comment: @revmatcher Good point, my bad.

Comment: From [this issue](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/4768), have you tried restarting Docker? Or if you're running M1, maybe look at [this issue](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/5282)?

Comment: Could you provide your entire terminal output when you run the docker command in question? It seems to be treating something as a path to a file or folder and not checking docker-hub for the image.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this error when running `docker login` without starting up the Docker Desktop on my Mac. So, don't forget to start it.

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked with

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 docker/getting-started
```

and

```
run docker ps
```

Command results:

CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS         PORTS                NAMES
83c7a6026d05   docker/getting-started   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   11 seconds ago   Up 9 seconds   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp   festive_beaver

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and realized I'd had docker installed from brew at some point in the past. I used

`brew uninstall docker`

Then killed all docker processes and did a Clean / Purge data, and restarted Docker Desktop. After that it took a minute or two to rebuild everything, but it worked for me.